# mexhttpbinding issue

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-6

I hosted my DLL in IIS 6 and set it to only allow authenticated users (disable anonymous). However, I am facing a problem on `mexHttpBinding`. It requires anonymous login to publish metadata.

I am doing something like this:

This is the original configuration:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration="wsBinding" />
```

And this is the binding property:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
    </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This resolves the issue, but I doubt this will work out actually.

Can I change `mexHttpBinding` to `wsHttpBinding` for `IMetadataExchange`?

Comment: If you find this site helpful, it is best to acknowledge correct answers to your questions to encourage other users to respond to your questions.

Comment: well, i am not sure i am doing right. just want to check with the wcf experts.

Comment: can i change mexHttpBinding to wsHttpBinding for IMetadataExchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a non-MEX Binding to retrieve metadata.  See [Retrieve Metadata Over a non-MEX Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730325.aspx) for a sample.